# Truly unique ranking (while ignoring empty cells)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using the following formulae for a truly unique ranking of values: [How to Rank Duplicate Values Sequentially](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/152567/en-us).

(As you may or may not be aware the other option (see ##) can produce erroneous results!)

However, there is a problem: I would like to ignore empty cells! Currently, empty cells are counted as having the value zero.

How do I need to change the formulae in [1](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/152567/en-us) to ignore empty cells and to return no value at all? Is that even possible with an array formula?

I avoid VBA as I need to keep this dynamic.

Thank you in advance for any hints!

pascal

(##): =RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$10)+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1

Comment: There are multiple formulas in your links - which is the one you are using? I'm not aware that the RANK/COUNTIF formula can produce "erroneous results", in what circumstances?

Comment: Hi Barry. I found the oddity that lead to the error. Now I don't understand the oddity. :(

http://i.imgur.com/FqhoquN.png

The same(!) value returns different ranks sometimes!! (I re-calculated the sheet).

Answer (score 3):

End result:

[image]

Method (A1 is top left):

```
Data2: =IF(ISBLANK($A2),"",VALUE($A2&"."&(ROW()-ROW($B$1))))

Sorted: =SMALL($B$2:$B$8,ROW()-ROW($C$1))

Rank: =IFERROR(MATCH($B2,$C$2:$C$8,0),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this formula should work OK, to create "unique ranks" and return blanks for blanks

`=IF(A2="","",RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$10)+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)`

I'd expect that to calculate correctly assuming `A2:A10` contains numbers (not text formatted) and where the numbers don't exceed 15 significant digits....but if you want to avoid `COUNTIF` then this formula with `SUMPRODUCT` should do the same:

`=IF(A2="","",SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$10>A2)*(A$2:A$10<>""))+SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A2=A2)*1))`

Comment: I think the first formula above is really neat and should work fine with non-integers as well. I found I had to modify it slightly to assign the higher ranks to the larger numbers:- =IF(A2="","",RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$10,1)+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)

Comment: The second formula works as well except that I had to change the first ">" to "<" :- =IF(A2="","",SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$10<A2)*(A$2:A$10<>""))+SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A2=A2)*1))